# Prove that $m^*([0,1]\setminus N)=1$ where $N$ is the Vitali set constructed in $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This is problem 32 (a) from Stein and Shakarchi's Real Analysis.

We are given the hint to consider the set U $\subseteq$ [0,1] such that [o,1]\N $\subseteq$ U and m*(U)=1-$\epsilon$ and proceed by contradiction.

(m* denotes the outer measure)

I have a suspicion we can use compliments to complete the proof.

Any ideas are much appreciated!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Math SE! I see you have tried to use special characters, which is very nice to see. Did you know that on this site, you can format your posts using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)? For example, type `$$[0,1]\setminus\Bbb{N}\subseteq U$$` to yield $$[0,1]\setminus\Bbb{N}\subseteq U$$ You can click on the link I provided for the tutorial. Again, welcome, and please keep contributing to this fantastic site! $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Is $m^\ast$ the **outer** Lebesgue measure? Is the task maybe to show $m^\ast ([0,1] \setminus N) = 1$ and not $m^\ast ([0,1] \setminus N) = 0$?

Comment: Whoops, edited the title to equal 1 and m* denotes the outer Lebesgue measure

Answer (score 0):

HINT:
It turns out that for every subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ we have
$$m^{\star}(A) = \inf \mu(U)$$ where $U$ is measurable and $U \supset A$.
So we can write
$$m^{\star}([0,1] \backslash N) = \inf_{ [0,1] \supset U \supset [0,1]\backslash N} m(U)= 1 - \sup_{V\subset N} m(V)$$ over all measurable subsets of $N$. Now use the fact that all the translates of $N$ by $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ are disjoint and included in $[0,2]$, so same is for any $V$ measurable $\subset N$. Therefore we must have $m(V)=0$ for any such $V$.